# Creating Mobile WebSite Which One To Use MVC Or .Net Mobile Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobilewebforms

I want to built website for Mobile Device i was search on the internet and found out that we can create using Asp.net MVC or Asp.net Mobile SDK..... then my query is which one should i go with ? MVC or Asp.net Mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you combine ASP.Net MVC application with [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) API. Thus, you can easily develop platform independent mobile applications which includes smartphone specific events and effects.